# Can equipment be re-equipped to another creature?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With Artifact equipment, say I've equipped it to one creature, and I want to move it to another, can it be equipped to another creature if I pay its equip cost again?

My thought process is that they aren't like Enchantment-Aura's which target a creature specifically, more so like an item that is not bound. Am I right in thinking then that they can be equipped more than once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if you have an Equipment attached to one creature, you can pay its equip cost to attach it to another creature. Every Equipment has the [Equip keyword ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Equip), which is defined in rule 702.6a as

> Equip is an activated ability of artifact Equipment cards. “Equip [cost]” means “[Cost]: **Attach this Equipment to target creature you control**. Activate this ability only any time you could play a sorcery.”

In addition, the [Attach keyword action](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Attach) that the Equip ability uses is defined in rule 701.2a as

> To attach an Aura, Equipment, or Fortification to an object means to take it from where it currently is and put it onto that object.

So, if an Equipment is already attached to a creature, when you activate its Equip ability, you move it from where it currently is (attached to the original creature) and put it onto the new creature.

One thing to keep in mind is that the Equip ability is an ability the Equipment has, not the creature. So if, for example, a [Suppression Bonds](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Suppression%20Bonds) is attached to the creature, you can still re-equip an Equipment attached to that creature. However, if the Suppression Bonds were instead attached to the Equipment itself, you would **not** be able to activate the Equip ability.

Comment: The reminder text (present on only some equipment) is a pretty good hint too; it doesn't say anything about the equip ability disappearing after you use it once.

Comment: That's a good point. The new Magic Origins game also has a pretty nice explanation of Equipment in the relevant skill quest.

Comment: Does this also apply to creatures that have been Locked in a powerless state as with One Thousand Lashes?

Comment: One Thousand Lashes prevents the *creature* from activating abilities. But the Equip ability is on the Equipment, not the creature. So no, it isn't affected. On the other hand, if you attach a Suppression Bonds directly to the Equipment, it *would* be prevented from re-equipping.

Comment: One useful move is to Equip a creature, attack with it, and then in your second main phase, move the equipment onto a creature you plan to block with. Handy, if you've got the spare mana.

Answer (score -1):

Reading though the rules it seems clear to me that if a creature is equipped and then that equipped creature is mind controlled, you can reattach that equipment to a creature you control.

Nobody ever does this though, like ever. The rules seem so clear but I don't want to try this due to fear of being shot down or violating some kind of play etiquette I don't know about.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question being asked here. If you want to know about mind controlling an equipped creature, you could ask it with the "Ask Question" link: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: Welcome to the site! This isn't an answer to the question, so it's going to get flagged and/or downvoted. That said, you're correct. The rules are very clear. Gaining control of the creature does not give you control of the artifact equipment. [CR 301.5d](http://wiki.magicjudges.org/en/w/CR:301.5d) makes this explicit. (Remember that you can only pay equip costs during the main phase of your turn.) If the people you play with don't play this way, then you need to educate them!

Comment: Is there a reason that my flag for this was declined? It seems clear to me that this isn't intended as an answer to the question being asked here, but rather a comment or question about handling equipment on a mind controlled creature.